# How to order ascending after compare 2 columns value and the condition is whichever lower?

Tags: mysql, select

I would like to compare 2 prices (price and discount price) and sort by lowest price (after compared) asc.

Here is my sample data

```
Item | price   | discount_price
================================
1    | 2000.00 | 1500.00
2    | 89.00   |    0.00
3    | 60.00   |   50.00
4    | 59.00   |    0.00
```

Here is my sample code:-

```
select item, price, discount_price from tableA order by
GREATEST(price,discount_price) desc
```

Result will show :-

```
Item | price   | discount_price
================================
1    | 2000.00 | 1500.00
2    | 89.00   |    0.00
3    | 60.00   |   50.00
4    | 59.00   |    0.00
```

What I expected is (get whichever is lower and sort accordingly)

```
Item | price   | discount_price
================================
1    | 2000.00 | 1500.00
2    | 89.00   |    0.00
4    | 59.00   |    0.00
3    | 60.00   |   50.00
```

Comment: You say *sort by lowest price (after compared) asc* and in your code you have: `order by GREATEST(price,discount_price) desc`. Can you explain what you want?

Comment: So if `discount_price` is 0, then it will take `price` and sort using the combination of that, correct?

Comment: hi @tcadidot0, yes u are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT item, price, discount_price FROM tableA 
ORDER BY IF(discount_price=0,price,discount_price) DESC;
```

The following query would also work:

```
SELECT item, price, discount_price FROM tableA 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN discount_price=0 THEN price ELSE discount_price END DESC;
```